# Insert Python DuckDB table into SQL statement

Tags: python, sql, pandas, duckdb

I am trying to use a registered virtual table as a table in a SQL statement using a connection to another database.  I can't just turn the column into a string and use that, I need the table/dataframe itself to work in the statement and join with the other tables in the SQL statment.  I'm trying this out on an Access database to start.  This is what I have so far:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import duckdb
conn = duckdb.connect()

starterset = pd.read_excel (r'e:\Data Analytics\Python_Projects\Applications\DB_Test.xlsx')

conn.register("test_starter", starterset)
IDS = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM test_starter WHERE ProjectID > 1").fetchdf()

StartDate = '1/1/2015'
EndDate = '12/1/2021'

# establish the connection
connt = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=E:\Databases\Offline.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Run the query
query = ("Select ProjectID, Revenue, ClosedDate from Projects INNER JOIN " + IDS + " Z on Z.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID "
"where ClosedDate between #" + StartDate + "# and #" + EndDate + "# AND Revenue > 0 order by ClosedDate")
sfd
df = pd.read_sql(query, connt)
    
df.to_excel(r'TEMP.xlsx', index=False)
os.system("start EXCEL.EXE TEMP.xlsx")

# Close the connection
cursor.close()
connt.close()
```

I have a list of IDs in the excel sheet that I'm trying to use as a filter from the database query.  Ultimately, this will form into several criteria from the same table: dates, revenue, and IDs among others.
Honestly, I'm surprised I'm having so much trouble doing this.  In SAS, with PROC SQL, it's so easy, but I can't get a dataframe to interface within the SQL parameters how I need it to.  Am I making a syntax mistake?
Most common error so far is "UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U55'), dtype('<U55')) -> dtype('<U55')", but the types are the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are pushing the contents of a DataFrame into an Access database query. I don't think there is a native way to do this in Pandas. The technique I use is database vendor specific, but I just build up a text string as either a CTE/WITH Clause or a temporary table.
Ex:
"""WITH my_data as (
SELECT 'raw_text_within_df' as df_column1, 'raw_text_within_df' as df_column2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'raw_text_within_df' as df_column1, 'raw_text_within_df' as df_column2
UNION ALL
...
)
[Your original query here]
"""